# Encryption request with access denied in pivotal config server

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

When I run the script below, I get the following return:

> {"error": "access_denied", "error_description": "Access is denied"}

How do I solve this problem?

```js
const request = require('request');
 
request({
  url: 'access_token_uri',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
    user: 'client_id',
    pass: 'client_secret'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
  encrypt(json.access_token, 'word');
});

function encrypt(token, word){
  request({
    url: 'uri/encrypt',
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
      'bearer': token
    },
    body: word
  }, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.body);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from your sample, but I think you're getting the wrong type of token.  For the `/encrypt` endpoint, you'd want a password based token.

See the section [Get a Password Credentials Access Token](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/service-broker-and-instances.html#get-access-token-for-direct-requests-to-a-service-instance) for more detals (I can't link directly to that section, you have to scroll down to that it using the previous link).

The process is basically this:

1. `cf login`
2. `cf oauth-token`
3. `curl -H "Authorization: <oauth-token>" https://uri/encrypt -d 'Value to be encrypted'`

If you want to see the API's being used by the `cf` cli, you can `export CF_TRACE=true` (Bash) or `set CF_TRACE=true` (Windows) then repeat the commands.  This will dump the HTTP request/response info.